# Hatcher hopf algebra sign convention

Tags: algebraic-topology, hopf-algebras, convention

I am reading 3.C in Hatcher's algebraic topology, where I was introduced to a sign convention for the product in $A\otimes A$ 
$$(a\otimes b)(c\otimes d)=(-1)^{|b||c|}(ac\otimes bd)$$

Does anybody know why we would adopt such a seemingly random convention? Instead of just doing away with the (-1).

Comment: This is called the Koszul sign rule. In the context of algebraic topology it's needed because the cup product in cohomology behaves this way (e.g. you need this to state the Kunneth theorem properly). You can see some discussion at https://mathoverflow.net/questions/354076/reason-to-apply-the-koszul-sign-rule-everywhere-in-graded-contexts .